# Random shadows - Flag & Cloth Simulation

Tags: mesh, cloth-simulation, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to make a flag but it shows me some random triangle shadows. I've tried to add subdivision surface without any success. Does anyone know why this is happening ?

[image]

Thank you

[image]

Comment: please add blend file

Comment: @Chris Added thank you.

Comment: as Emir already answered right...change cube size to 64 - > this helps

Answer (score 1):

From the Image, looks like your shadows are in EEVEE, which means that you need to increase the Shadows Resolution. You can do this inside the Render Settings > Shadows.

[image]