# Eevee Sunlight Contact Shadows cause unwanted flickering shadows

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, shadows

When I turn on contact shadows, unwanted shadows appear. When I change the viewing angle they flicker.

[image]
Contact Shadows off.

[image]
Contact Shadows on.

[image]

How can this be avoided without turning off Contact Shadows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random shadows - Flag & Cloth Simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244394/random-shadows-flag-cloth-simulation)

Comment: I did try that but it did not help. But I found another solution to the problem. Instead of using contact shadows I sat the Distribution to 1, witch gave the same effect as contact shadows but without the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using contact shadows I sat the Distribution to 1, witch gave the same effect as contact shadows but without the problem.

[image]