# Flickering of shadows and lights in eevee animation

Tags: rendering, lighting, shadows, emission

I've been trying to figure out why my emission shader and shadows flicker in eevee when I render this as an animation. I experimented with light and shadow settings, samples, viewport and camera clip settings, z fighting issues, baking, bloom settings, nothing changes the odd effect of flickering when the animation starts. I've attached a gif of the effect with real-time material rendering to quickly demonstrate the problem, but I have also rendered many times with proper rendering.

I have also attached the .blend file.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random shadows - Flag & Cloth Simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244394/random-shadows-flag-cloth-simulation)

Comment: Thanks for helping! Unfortunately that did not work.